# Do the variance and bias belong to the policy or value functions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, statistical-ai, bias-variance-tradeoff

Recently, I read many papers on variance and bias. But I am still confused by the two notions, the variance or bias belongs to who? Policy or value? If the variance or bias is large or low, what results will we get?